# Can I convert an app configured in AOSP to an app using gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, open-source, android-source, android-build

I have my legacy version System App which consists of mk files from AOSP.

However, debugging or modifying this app is time-consuming and tedious because you have to port it after building the entire platform.

I just want to modify this app and add features within android studio like the apps I've developed in the past.

Most of the dependencies written in the existing mk file could be configured using gradle script, but androidstudio fails to build because of the part that uses system api or the part where the framework itself is customized.

is there a way for me?

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into two major parts:

For dependencies on Android Application component based Java code:

Try to make a list of all the dependencies you have there and add
them via imports if they're a part of the public Android SDK, and /
or add them to your app via the dependencies block in the module's
build.gradle as an implementation. Make sure to add google() and
mavenCentral() in the repositories. (Plenty of guides on how to add
a dependency of a third party library). And then gradle sync.

For customized framework dependency:

I think the best way to add any custom framework dependency is to add it as a compileOnly file / or implementation / api in the build.gradle of whatever module you have in the app source code on your project as an AAR or a JAR file. To generate this custom framework AAR / JAR (like a CustomServiceManager.java), build that specific module in AOSP environment if it can be built independently or via make framework / make services.

Ref: https://medium.com/@chauyan/import-aosp-framework-jar-file-f0c2ac979a8a

Comment: I made good use of your comment and created a custom framework jar and included it in the dependencies, but I got an error about duplicate imports and it got out of hand. so i just gave up

Comment: Can you share some sample code and error logs - maybe on Github?

Comment: To briefly explain here, I was able to import various dependencies through maven or google as you taught me, but the project I am developing uses system api, and I frequently use methods with system api annotations. Of course, you can call the corresponding methods individually through reflection, but it was not easy to implement over 100 methods through reflection. Also, if you add a jar created through build as a dependency to use classes that are used only in custom frameworks, a build error will occur because the jar file is duplicated with the library imported from maven or google

Comment: That is the actual problem to solve, perhaps, no luck guessing here!